# Automate git staging

Tags: git

I work with a bunch of different CMSs.  Often we need to upgrade the components.  When doing so, I'm finding that nearly all of my files are showing changes because the copyright has changed on all of them.  Often times this can be 500-1000 different files that I have to go through one by one and stage.  What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to say "If there's only one change and it's line 2 changes from 2013 to 2014 -- then automatically stage this file".  Then afterward we could go through and only have to verify the changes for those files where the actual code has changed.

I'm not sure how possible this is, but I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can run through the files one at a time and then analyze the output of 'git diff' for each file to see if they match your criteria, and only stage the ones that do.  Git diff uses "+ " at the beginning of each added file, so checking for that and counting will give you number of lines modified.  Make sure only one line was modified and make sure it has the word "Copyright" in it.

```
for modifiedFile in $(git ls-files --modified)

do

  linesModified=$(git diff ${modifiedFile} | grep ^\+\  | wc -l)

   if [ ${linesModified} -eq 1 ]
   then

      copyrightOnly=$(git diff ${modifiedFile} | grep ^\+\  | grep Copyright | wc -1)

      if [ ${copyrightOnly} -eq 1 ]
      then

         git add ${modifiedFile}
      fi
   fi
done
```